# Does "_" have a shortcut for creating a key => value object?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I often find myself in the situation where I need the following construction:

```
function keyValuePair(key, value) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
};
```

This is pretty handy, when you need to create an object, whose key is determined dynamically:

```
var name = "someProperty";
var myObj = keyValue('prefix.' + name, 123);
```

which is often the case when you're working with MongoDB queries for example.

Is it possible to achieve the same result with `lodash` or `underscore`?

Comment: So you define a function to turn what should be 3 lines of functional code into 7 lines of functional code? There would be very little point unless you had multiple keys. Was about to comment about ES6 but someone just answered.

Comment: Ideally I would prefer it to be only one line of code. That's why I need that helper function. Makes sense? So counting this as 7 lines, is not really correct.

Comment: Well seven lines in place of three looks pretty correct to me. Pulling in external dependencies for even more bloat, also counts to me as well. So before you praise "helpers" you might just consider your code coverage of usage of the functions and how much that actually brings to the party on the inclusion. Also part of the point I was originalyl going to make is that ES6 has a nicer syntax for this anyway, which makes it a one liner.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I wouldn't ask this question if I hadn't used this "helper" a dozen of times, believe me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `underscore` you may do the following:

```
_.object(['key'], ['value'])
```

which results an object

```
{
  'key': 'value'
}
```

Documentation on [_.object](http://underscorejs.org/#object)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

With ES6 you can do the following

```
var myObj = {[`prefix.${name}`]: 123};
```

Which looks and feels a lot nicer.

You will want to use **[Babel](https://babeljs.io/)** or a similar framework to transpile it to ES5 code for the time being though.

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting ES6 must offer some kind of solution, but for know I would prefer to stick with ES5.

Comment: @apendua In that case, have a look at Igor's answer. I'm not familiar with a better way

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lodash, the [set()](https://lodash.com/docs#set) method works well for this:

```
var myObj = _.set({}, 'prefix.name', 'foo');
console.log(myObj.prefix.name);
// → foo
```

Comment: That's interesting too. Thanks! The only problem with this solution I can see is that it will result in `{ prefix: { name: 'foo' }}` rather then `{ 'prefix.name': 'foo' }`. Think of nested mongoDB queries to see why I need the latter version.